# The best publishing platform for a business "vanity" book?

Tags: publishing, business-writing

I have a client who has written a (well done) synopsis of his core business proposition that reads like a great little book, but is only 15,000 words. Is this a good candidate for Amazon's Singles? Are there other similar, more business-focused platforms for publication/distribution of such a teaser?

Does every book that applies for publication through the Kindle Singles platform get approved -- or are they more of a publisher than a platform provider? Do they make decisions about what type of "singles" are appropriate or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the standard Kindle self-publishing program offered by Amazon, you can choose to create an e-book out of just about any content you desire. Amazon doesn't have a lot of restrictions, especially in regards to business books, so getting the book out there really isn't an issue.

However, the Amazon Singles do have to go through an approval process, and Amazon is much more selective about what gets released in that manner. You should think of the Amazon Singles as more of traditional publishing model in that you would have to submit your book to them for consideration and then they would decide whether or not to include it in that program.

I did some research in a couple of other forums, and the consensus seems to be that the stories selected for Amazon Singles seem to be selected pretty much by invitation. In other words, Amazon sought them out by either choosing stories they found through other sources (magazines or newspapers) or by soliciting well known writers to submit shorter stories specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Lulu](http://www.lulu.com/)? They've been around for many years.

http://www.lulu.com/publish/books/

My husband just told me about "[Blurb](http://www.blurb.com/)", another self publishing site he read about on INC magazine, but I've never heard of them before otherwise. There is even a webinar: [Create your Business Portfolio with a Book](http://www.blurb.com/webinars)